# How to calculate the width of violin at given value

Tags: r, probability, distributions, quantiles

I have been searching for this, but I couldn't find a salutation. I know we could calculate at what values the quantiles are of a violin plot. But I was wondering how we could calculate the width of a violin plot at a given value y. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
set.seed(7)
df = data.frame(y = rnorm(100, 2, 1))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = y)) +
  geom_violin(, fill = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So imagine I would like to calculate the violin width at **y = 3**. How are we supposed to calculate this using the y values?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378184/extract-data-from-a-ggplot).

Comment: Hi @Bergson, Yes you are right. That's a way to get the width, but image you want to have the width at exactly the value y = 3, then it is not possible to use that approach because it doesn't return the width for that given value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The violins in ggplot are created with the 'density' function from core R.

The settings are to use a Gaussian kernel with the `nrd0` algorithm to define the bandwidth (see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/bandwidth.html)).

[image: example]

This code shows how to generate the density that is used for plotting the violin

```
### this will plot the result from the denisty function
plot(density(df$y, bw = "nrd0", kernel = "gaussian"), ylim = c(0,1))

### with the bandwidth computed with nrd0, which is 0.3419, 
### we can also manually compute the density as following

### the values of x used for plotting
x = seq(min(df$y),max(df$y),0.1)

### compute a sum of Gaussians
### centered at y
### (note that the 'density' function
### uses a faster Fourier transform
### to make the computation, 
### but this loop shows more intuively 
### what happens)
width = sapply(x, FUN = function(x) {
   mean(dnorm(df$y-x,0, 0.3419))
})

### add points to the graph
points(x,width)
```